# ReactJS -> Why does my state return undefined on the first try?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to save the loginState of a user in a state and then send it to a cookie. The thing is that the first time I log in through my login form I set the loginState to 'logged in', then I console log it but it returns undefined and then on the second press of the button login(after I've already logged in successfully) it finally says 'logged in' in the console. Why is that? How do I fix it?
Here's the relevant code:

```
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus]= useState()
    //Here we have irrelevant code that validates the login info entered and then it calls authorizeUser
    const authorizeUser=()=>{
      setLoginStatus('logged in')
      console.log(loginStatus)
}
```

Comment: It is asynchronous and it doesn't update immediately when you set state.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you can use the `useEffect` hook to log the updated state: `useEffect(() => { console.log(loginStatus); }, [loginStatus]);`

Comment: @Beyond so even though it doesn't log it into the console, after pressing the button it is still set, although it does not show it right away?

Comment: @Python_Mython79 yes. It will not show up in your component until the next re-render. React batches state updates for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` runs *after* every render, so even if you're setting the value of `loginStatus` in `useEffect()`, on the *first* render `loginStatus` will have no value. You can set a default value *before* the first render by passing a default value in your call to `useState()`, like this:

`const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState('whatever you want here, even a null string')`